# Changing internal database to external JDBC in Atlassian crowd

Tags: centos, atlassian-crowd

I have installed Atlassian crowd using the internal database method on Centos 6. Installation went successfully and now I want to use external database (mysql) using JDBC. I cant find the option to accomplish that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually documented in Atlassian's own wiki, see "[Migrate to Another Database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Migrate+to+Another+Database)".